# Jquery requests spawning high number of apache processes

Tags: jquery, linux, apache, optimization

We have an emergency situation with one of our customers. There is live pricing on their site, we perform a jquery request every 5 seconds to an external XML feed. I can restart apache and it immediately ramps up the apache processes to our MaxClients setting (150 httpd processes), thus no longer serving webpages to others. If we block the IP of that external xml feed the server runs great, only 65 httpd processes are running and apache runs great.

We run a LAMP stack. They have under 100 end users on their website at one time (varies) on a single apache server. What we think may be happening is the external XML feed may be throttling excessive requests from our IP and giving us a 500 or 404 error, perhaps leaving stale apache connections open and never closing them. My first thought was to decrease PHP timeout but that's not a good solution for a single jquery request bringing down our entire webserver.

Comment: if you have 100 customers on the website, each requesting pricing data for 1 or more products every 5 seconds, of course you're going to hit the 150 cap. You may be able to make this a little bit better by using long-polling

Comment: long-polling would reduce the number of requests per minute by a large amount, depending on how large of a timeout you use and how often the data changes.

Comment: Thanks guys. We are going to put a static .txt file on our local server that's updated by apache once every five seconds with the latest information from an external source. This is different because instead of the users having to reach out to another server for the latest information they just look to a local flat file for the information. I'm concerned this will still spawn new connections to reach out to the localserver however.

Comment: Anyway to make sure these requests don't open a new connection every 5 seconds, and instead reuse an existing connection?